# Current version of HPLIP

Tags: upgrade, printing

Why in an Ubuntu system, after installing a newer version of HPLIP, if I give

```
dpkg -l hplip
```

I get the older version yet (i.e. the preinstalled one in the system)?

Comment: Which version of `hplip` does you have?

Comment: `dpkg -l` only shows those applications that were installed using `apt` or `dpkg`, i.e., softwares that were installed using `.deb` files. Whereas the latest version of `hplip` comes in binary format. That might be the reason it is not shown under the command you used. Also, it seems you didn't uninstall `hplip` before installing a new one from the binary file. So, uninstall the previous `hplip` using `apt-get` and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Raphael pointed out, the latest version of `hplip` was released on their website, plus it comes in `.run` executable.

In my 16.04, the default `hplip` version was `3.16.3`, whilst their website offer more version than the default. So it possible you've install newer version of `hplip` via website.

So if you successfully install the latest version (via `.run` installer) from their official website, `hplip` might have been upgraded but you just don't notice it. Try run `hp-setup` on terminal to check whether the version listed as your desired version. Example output:

```
Liso@thinkpad:~$ hp-setup

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.
```

If none of version listed correctly as they should be, [try removing `hplip` and reinstall it again](http://hplipopensource.com/node/188).

Comment: .@Liso&Raphael: yes, that's true, I didn't purge the old hplip. Again the non-use of a deb,indeed I used the Manual Install (using so a tar.gz), because the Automatic one gave me a trouble in the "sudo" phase (I think it was a bug of the Installer). I had also tried the hp-setup to configure the device, and I noticed the version was the right one, that just installed from the site. So my doubt wasn't if I had succesfully obtained the most recent version,but why that command showed me the preceding one. So the reason is the non-use of a deb file (and not the non-removal of the previous version?